# query on properties in /system/build.prop

Tags: android, heap-memory, dalvik

Could some one please explain me regarding the below properties in build.prop,

```
dalvik.vm.heapstartsize=5m
dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit=48m
dalvik.vm.heapsize=128m
dalvik.vm.heaptargetutilization=0.75
dalvik.vm.heapminfree=512k
dalvik.vm.heapmaxfree=2m
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Walking through the list:

```
dalvik.vm.heapstartsize=5m
```

This is [converted](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/jni/AndroidRuntime.cpp) to a `-Xms` option for Dalvik.  It specifies the initial size of the managed heap.

```
dalvik.vm.heapsize=128m
```

This is converted to a `-Xmx` option for Dalvik.  It specifies the maximum size of the managed heap.

```
dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit=48m
```

This converts to a `-XX:HeapGrowthLimit` option.  It specifies the maximum size of a "standard" app's heap.  If the app uses `android:largeHeap` in its manifest, it uses the full heapsize value instead.

```
dalvik.vm.heaptargetutilization=0.75
```

This converts to a `-XX:HeapTargetUtilization` option.  It gives the VM a hint as to how full the managed heap should be allowed to become.

```
dalvik.vm.heapminfree=512k
dalvik.vm.heapmaxfree=2m
```

These converts to `-XX:HeapMinFree` and `-XX:HeapMaxFree`, respectively.  These are used in conjunction with the the `XX:HeapTargetUtilization` to determine how much to grow the heap when the heap needs to grow.

For more details, see the [HeapSource sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/alloc/HeapSource.cpp).